# How can I load a single price, that's valid on a given date when the data has valid from and to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a price list and different customers get a different price depending on when they signed up for my service.

Each customer has a created date and the price has a valid from and to date unless it's the current price then the to date is null.

How can I get the price of a given item for a given customer created date.

Here's my price list.

```
PriceId Rate      ValidFrom     ValidTo
26708   1.0000    2013-07-10    NULL
26709   100.0000  2013-07-10    2014-05-01
```

And my first attempt at a query which doesn't quite work.

```
DECLARE @CreatedDate datetime2 = '2014-01-01'

SELECT * 
FROM [PriceList] 
where ValidFrom < @CreatedDate and (ValidTo > @CreatedDate or ValidTo is null)
```

This works for new customers where they are imported after the new price has been created but for old customers I get both prices. I know why I get both prices but can't quite figure out how to not get the one with a null ValidTo date.

I'll happily set the ValidTo date to a value rather than null if that helps. I can probably fix this with a common table expression but I'd need to change a major part of my application to do that, I'm really looking for a where clause that'll cover it but my brain can't come up with one at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried between?

```
DECLARE @CreatedDate datetime2 = '2014-01-01'

SELECT * 
FROM [PriceList] 
where @CreatedDate BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo
```

Although, you wouldn't want to leave ValidTo Null. At an old job we set the date to 1-1-2999
if you have to leave it null

```
DECLARE @CreatedDate datetime2 = '2014-01-01'

SELECT * 
FROM [PriceList] 
where @CreatedDate BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ISNULL(ValidTo, '1/1/2999')
```

Comment: Of course, I thought I'd tried this and failed but it's quite simple if I set the to date to be the maximum date. I can't use between because I'm converting a URL query into SQL but if I just do `ValidFrom > @CreatedDate and ValidTo < @CreatedDate` I get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you have a bad data structure if you have overlapping prices.  You can do what you want using `top`:

```
select top 1 pl.*
from pricelist pl
where ValidFrom < @CreatedDate and (ValidTo > @CreatedDate or ValidTo is null)
order by ValidFrom desc,
         (case when ValidTo is null then 0 else 1 end),
         ValidTo desc;
```

This prioritizes the rows based on the valid dates and chooses one -- either the most recent `ValidFrom`.  If there are duplicates in that, then an arbitrary row where `ValidTo` is `NULL`.  If none are `NULL`, then the latest `ValidTo`.

Comment: We shouldn't have overlapping dates, when a new price is added the old price for that item is retired

Comment: What structure would you suggest for this sort of arrangement.

Comment: @BenCr . . . When a new price is added, the `ValidTo` date of the previous current price should be set to the new date minus one day.

Comment: That gives us a day where there are no prices, a customer created on that missing day won't be able to buy that item. I'm confident that I don't need that buffer but I could be wrong. Why do I need to add/subtract that day?

Comment: @BenCr . . . So the begin and end dates are inclusive and you can use `between`.  I also think it makes more logical sense that way; a price is valid for the period specified on the row.  But you can put in the day after the end date, if you prefer.

Comment: I've actually got times on my begin and end days and a created time so I can be very specific with my > and <. I just removed them from the question for simplicity

Comment: @BenCr . . . When there are times, then you want >= starttime and < endtime, and for the starttime of one record to match the endtime of the previous record.

Comment: Perhaps but the margin for error there is now in the 1000ths of a second and in reality we stop creating new customers while we update our price list so it's not essential that we're that accurate.

Comment: @BenCr . . . That sounds like the kind of bug that is really, really hard to find.  I would suggest uniformity and having the end time of one record match the start time of the next.